# Regular expression to match at least One capital letter and at least One digit and any number of special charecter

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I'm new to this regular expression. Please help me on this query.

I want the Regular expression to match at least One capital letter and at least One digit and any number of special characters. Minimum length 8 and maximum length can be 15.

Note : The special characters allowed are **@#$&.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This site might be helpful: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks guys. I found the answer.

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*[^a-zA-Z0-9@#$^+=])(.{8,15})$/
```

Comment: any explanation?

Answer (score 5):

Regex:

```
[A-Z]+[0-9]+[@#\$&]*
```

And for the length part, use:

```
var len = str.length;

if( /[A-Z]/.test(str) && /[0-9]/.test(str) && len >= 8 && len <= 15 )
```

`[A-Z]` - one capital letter
`[0-9]` - one digit

`[abc]` means any of `a`, `b`, or `c`.

http://regex101.com/r/aE5hL4

Comment: Not working. The order of input can vary. It should match that also. For example : aaa34Assf@

Comment: @PaRsH Since, it can have any number of special characters (zero also), no need to check it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work (unless you want to match newlines too):

```
/(?:[A-Z].*[0-9])|(?:[0-9].*[A-Z])/
```

(I missed the length restriction, but anyway you seem satisfied with what you got there.)